# Is there a way to place an object of higher layer behind an object in a lower layer?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I have many elements like a phone, a pencil, a clock etc. in their own individual layers. Then I have a layer that has elements like eyes, mouth, hands and legs.

Now, I always want the eyes and the mouth to stay on top of the elements while the arms and legs in the bottom. Can I do that without taking the **human** elements out of a single layer

**EXAMPLE**

This is how my layers are stacked up currently :-

> layer human elements
>
> layer phone
>
> layer pencil

In this scenario my image looks like this :-
[image]

*notice the arms are on top of the edge of the phone*

But I want it to look like this :-
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things you can do.

Option 1: make the arms a separate layer and place it behind the phone later.

Option 2: make the arms stop at the phone, and not overlap it. You could draw that with the pen tool quickly.

Comment: this is what I am doing right now. I don't think what I want is possible

Comment: If you make a separate layer for the arms then it should defiantly be possible, as long as the screen of the phone is a color filled rectangle.